# how to format in RTF using c#?

Tags: c#, rtf

I have below text in richTextBox control.

[image]

i want to format text like below text

[image]

Comment: You want to do this programmatically?

Comment: i want to do this programmatically in c#.

Comment: What is the source of the text? Is it always the same or is it a file or...?

Comment: dynamic text but input text is like that format.

Answer (score 1):

The RTF box can help you here, the only help using RTF will be using a table as Kosala mentioned.

You may use string operations for that:

```
int equalPos = 20;
for (int l = 0; l < rtfBox.Lines.Length; l++) {
    int i = rtfBox.lines[i].IndexOf('=');
    int n = equalPos - i;
    if ((i >= 0) && (n > 0)) {
        rtfBox.lines[i] = rtfBox.lines[i].Insert(i, new string(' ', n));
    }
}
```

Wrote this from head, so please check for errors.

**EDIT:**
Ok, here's another one:

```
for (int l = 0; l < rtfBox.Lines.Length; l++) {
    int i = rtfBox.lines[i].IndexOf('=');
    if (i >= 0) {
        rtfBox.lines[i] = rtfBox.lines[i].Insert(i, "\t");
    }
}
rtfBox.SelectAll();
rtfBox.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 100 };  // Find a value big enough!
```

Comment: i have tried that code but format is not accurate because of char width is different in pixel.

Comment: I you want exact column widths, you have to use a font that has equal character sizes. In your screenshots you used Consolas, which has equals char width.

Comment: this is the richtextbox, so end user can change font name and size.

Comment: Please use the second code, instead od replacing `' '` with `'\t'`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.(These are manual steps.. :)

1).Open MSWord.

2).Create a table; 2 columns and 5 rows (this is for your text)

3). put the text that you wanted to format in to correct cells of the table

4). Save Word Doc as a rtf file.

5). Open rtf file in notepad(notepad++ is better)

There it is.. Now you can find how it is formatted. Now it should not be hard for you to do it in C#. Good luck.